# Parent changing child's attribute

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, attributes, parent-child

I want to have class-based counter, storing the number of instances created.

It could be implemented as such:

```
class Parent(object):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        # remembers the order in which the instances were created
        self.counter = counter
        Parent.counter += 1
```

And I want to have numerous `Child` classes doing the same, i.e. each `Child` class should have a separate `counter`.

Since the logic is the same, I feel I should be able to increment the child class's counter from the parent's `__init__` method, instead of copy-pasting it.

Comment: So,what's your problem?

Comment: @zoosuck presumably, the fact that having an immutable class attribute means that using `self.counter` will create a new instance attribute but specifying `Parent.counter` means that the `Child` class attribute is ignored.

Comment: What you wrote raises a `NameError` for `counter`. You probably wanted to write `self.counter = Parent.counter; Parent.counter += 1` (actually, `self.counter = self.counter; Parent.counter += 1` would achieve the same, although it looks strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to increment the child's counter from the parent -- but you've hard-coded the class.

```
def __init__(self):
    type(self).counter += 1
```

should do the trick...

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...   counter = 0
...   def __init__(self):
...     type(self).counter += 1
... 
>>> class C1(Parent): pass
... 
>>> class C2(Parent): pass
... 
>>> C1().counter
1
>>> C1().counter
2
>>> C1().counter
3
>>> C2().counter
1
>>> C2().counter
2
>>> C2().counter
3
```

Be careful, though... if `Parent` ever has its `counter` incremented, then all future children will start at that value.

```
>>> Parent.counter = 3.14159
>>> class C3(Parent): pass
... 
>>> C3().counter
4.14159
```

Current children will be unaffected:

```
>>> C2().counter
4
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammar @jonrsharpe.  That's what I get for StackOverflowing before 7 AM... :-)

Comment: You're welcome - it's mid-afternoon here, so I've no such excuse!

Comment: I dunno... Mid-afternoon is (in some ways) worse than early morning!  :-)  And, if I'm to be honest with myself, the real problem is that I haven't paid enough attention to my grammar as of late so it's slipping a bit.  I should be more careful... (no matter what time of day it is)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to have a *class method* for updating the `counter`:

```
class Parent(object):

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = self.counter  # get the current value of the class attribute
        self.increment_counter()

    @classmethod
    def increment_counter(cls):
        cls.counter += 1


class Child1(Parent):
    pass


class Child2(Parent):
    pass
```

In use:

```
>>> c1a = Child1()
>>> c1b = Child1()
>>> c2a = Child2()
>>> Parent.counter
0  # no Parent instances
>>> Child1.counter
2  # two Child1 instances
>>> Child2.counter
1  # one Child2 instance
>>> c2a.counter
0
>>> c1b.counter
1
>>> c2a.counter
0
```

Note, however, that reusing the name `counter` for both the number of instances on each class (`ClassName.counter`) and which number each instance is (`instance.counter`) makes it harder to access the former from an instance method.